# Cypress (version 10): failed to read dockerfile

Tags: docker, dockerfile, cypress

[image: My docker file]

I am new to docker and I am following the exact steps mentioned in a Udemy course. When I enter the command as per below I a getting failed to read dockerfile error. please help.
[image]

Comment: Are you sure you have `Dockerfile` inside folder, where you run your `docker build` comnand?

Comment: Thank you for pointing out that. I checked again and I was not running the docker command inside the folder which the docker file is. Then I again ran the docker command inside the folder which has a docker file and it worked. But now I am getting another error.

Comment: => ERROR [6/7] RUN $(npm bin)/cypress verify                                                                                                         0.8s 
------
 > [6/7] RUN $(npm bin)/cypress verify:
#10 0.783 /bin/sh: 1: /app/node_modules/.bin/cypress: not found

Comment: Essentially what this tells is that you don't have `cypress` installed. It's not installed in `cypress/base` image. I think that this image here better serves your needs, because it has cypress already installed: https://hub.docker.com/r/cypress/included

Comment: I was able to solve it. I added the docker file inside the cypress folder, that is why it was not working. When I move it outside and try it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@qaziqarta's question helped me out. I checked again and I was not running the docker command inside the folder which the docker file is. Then I again ran the docker command inside the folder which has a docker file and it worked. But now I am getting another error.

[image]

update--> I was able to solve it. I added a docker file inside the cypress folder, that is why it was not working. When I move it outside and try it worked.